# Please find the quadratic form solution

Tags: matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

Let

$q(x) =x_1^2+x_2^2+3x_3^2-2x_1x_3+2x_2x_3+x_1+x_3+5 =x^TQx+b^Tx+5$

$ \begin{matrix}
  x=(    x_1 & x_2 & x_3 )^T\\
  \end{matrix}
$

the first question was find a symmetric matrix Q and a vector b. so I found that matrix by using way to solve quadratic form

$$
  Q=     \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
       -1 & 1 & 3 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

## and $$ b =\begin{matrix}
        (1 & 0 & 1)^T\\
       \end{matrix}$$

The second question was 'find, in terms of Q and b and find the minimum of q(x)'

If $ \partial q(x)/∂x=
\begin{matrix}
        (∂q/∂x_1& ∂q/∂x_2&∂q/∂x_3)^T\\
       \end{matrix}$

how can I solve second question?
how can I approach in good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanna share my try,

I guess we can find the minimum of this function by differentiation. Let's find our critical points, that is
$$ \exists x_{0} \in R^3, / \bigtriangledown  q(x_{0})=0?$$
note that $q(x): R^3 \rightarrow R$
$$\bigtriangledown  q(x)=(2x-2z+1,2y+2z,6z-2x+2y+1)$$
Now we should solve the following system

$2x-2z+1=0$

$2y+2z=0$

$6z-2x+2y+1=0$

it's east to find $x_{o}=(-3/2 , 1,-1)$ as its solution. Thus we just need to check if the Hessian is a positive matrix (cause it implies this point is a minimum). If you derivative again, you'll find:

$ Hq(x_{o})=
\begin{matrix}
        2 & 0 & -2 \\
        0 & 2 & 2 \\
       -2 & 2 & 6 \\
        \end{matrix}
$

As far as I remember there is a theorem which relate Hessian with the quadratic form, check your notes cause it will help. However, in our case $Hq(x_{0})=2Q$, then we just need to check if Q is a positive matrix.
$A_{1} >0, A_{2}>0, A_{3}>0$ so Q is a positive matrix thus $x_{0}$ is the minimum of q(x) $\forall b$

Comment: it was really good help to understand thank you.

Comment: It's better to use correct English: "wanna" $\rightarrow$ "want to" (I am not native English speaker)